# Array from database is showing field name and not value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database table where each record has many possible "answers".  I want to pull one of those records, and display a random value from that record.  All of this is working fine, however, it is showing the field's name rather than the value in that field.

Here is how I am getting the record:

```
if (isset($_GET['choice'])) {
 $colname_getBeginning = $_GET['choice'];
}
$json = array();
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_getSentence = sprintf("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE ID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getBeginning, "int"));
$getSentence = mysql_query($query_getSentence, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
while ( $row_getSentence = mysql_fetch_assoc($getSentence)) {
$json[] = $row_getSentence;
 }
```

And then, with the result, I am doing this:

```
$new_array = array_slice($json[0],1,9);
$random_key = array_rand($new_array);
$answer1 = json_encode($random_key);
echo $row_getBeginning['question'] . $answer1;
```

It should show something like:  My favorite animals are "chickens".  Instead it says, My favorite animals are "ANS4".   That is the field name for the field that was randomly chosen.   Why isn't it showing the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out array_rand returns the "key" of an array and not the value.  So, changing my last bit of code to this fixed the problem:

```
new_array = array_slice($json[0],1,9);
$random_key = array_rand(array_flip($new_array));
$answer1 = $random_key;
echo $row_getBeginning['question'] . $answer1;
```

Notice the array_flip in the second line.  This flips the array so that keys become values or values become keys.   Also, I took out the encode_json.   Apparently, having that makes quotes show up around the key/value and not using it shows the key/value without quotes.  Not sure what purpose that has.